# Autocomplete - how change ul on div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

***Good day.***

***Standart jquery autocomlete forming result in `<ul>`:***

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                //.append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )

                .append('<a href="http://testwork.ru/id' + item.uid + '" class="ts_contact  clear_fix write" id="ts_contact' + item.uid + '" target="_blank">' +
                '<span class="ts_contact_photo fl_l">' +
                '<img src="' + item.icon + '">' +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="ts_contact_name fl_l">' + item.value +
                '<div class="ts_contact_info">' + item.desc + '</div>' +
                "</span>" +
                '<div class="ts_contact_status"></div>' +
                '</a>')

                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

***in firebug we can see:***

[image: test]

***But now i would like change `<ul>` on `<div class="example">`.***

***Anybody has ideas how make this ?***

Comment: Do you want to replace the `ul` with a `div`?

Comment: jQuery UI is pretty strict when it comes to theming, maybe you can play with its css and js files, but I am not sure you can do this easily without getting involved deep into its code.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin yes, i want replace scheme `<ul> <li> <a>` on scheme `<div> <a>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the `ul` you will have to change the element after the creation of the plugin, for example:

```
var auto = $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ ... });

var oldparent = auto.data('uiAutocomplete').menu.element.parent();

auto.data('uiAutocomplete').menu =  $('<div></div>').addClass( "ui-autocomplete ui-front" )
            .appendTo(oldparent)
            .menu({ role: null })
            .hide()
            .data( "menu" );
```

A demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fx74j/).

Comment: But also me need delete `<li></li>` **see image [here](http://s4.uploads.ru/4QhVu.png)**. That will be only `<div><a></a></div>`. How make this?

Comment: @LeoLoki Check again the demo, and notice the `renderItem` function, there isn´t any `li`

Comment: @LeoLoki obviously I used custom data in the demo as I don´t have access to your data, but the process is the same